# How to Parse Json in Kotlin Using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

i am new to kotlin and i am in learning phase. I have followed many links but didn't able to understand completely.
I want Json response to show in my textview.

**Problem: 1**
I have tried this code but was unable to get data, but i want to get the items inside **data** object. Quote and author are coming null.

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "Success",
"data": {
    "Quote": "The pain you feel today will be the strength you feel tomorrow.",
    "Author": ""
},
"time": "0.14 s"
```

}

**Problem: 2**
I dont know how to parse this response in textview

```
object ServiceBuilder {

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://url.com.pk/") // change this IP for testing by your actual machine IP

    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()

fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
    return retrofit.create(service)
}}
```

**RestApi**

```
interface  RestApi{
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/getquotes")
abstract fun addUser(@Body userData: UserInfo): Call<UserInfo>}
```

**RestAPiService**

```
class RestApiService
{
    fun addUser(userData: UserInfo, onResult: (UserInfo?) -> Unit)
    {
        val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)
        retrofit.addUser(userData).enqueue(
            object : Callback<UserInfo>
            {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserInfo>, t: Throwable)
                {
                    onResult(null)
                }

                override fun onResponse( call: Call<UserInfo>, response: Response<UserInfo>)
                {
                    val addedUser = response.body()
                    Log.d("responsee",""+addedUser)
                    onResult(addedUser)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**UserInfo**

```
data class UserInfo (

    @SerializedName("Quote")
    val quote : String,

    @SerializedName("Author")
    val author : String
)
```

**MainActivity**

```
 fun getQuotes() {
        val apiService = RestApiService()
        val userInfo = UserInfo("","")

        apiService.addUser(userInfo) {
            Log.d("Error registering user","errter")
            /*if ( != null)
            {
                // it = newly added user parsed as response
                // it?.id = newly added user ID
            } else {
                Log.d("Error registering user","errter")
            }*/
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status, message and data are all part of the response so you need to take care of that. For example this

```
data class AddUserResponse(
    val `data`: UserInfo, //like you defined it
    val message: String,
    val status: Int,
    val time: String
)
```

This means parameter and response are different so the RestApi needs to be changed to this

```
abstract fun addUser(@Body userData: UserInfo): Call<AddUserResponse>}
```

This in turn also change the types in the service like

```
class RestApiService
{
    fun addUser(userData: UserInfo, onResult: (UserInfo?) -> Unit)
    {
        val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)
        retrofit.addUser(userData).enqueue(
            object : Callback<AddUserResponse>
            {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<AddUserResponse>, t: Throwable)
                {
                    onResult(null)
                }

                override fun onResponse( call: Call<AddUserResponse>, response: Response<AddUserResponse>)
                {
                    val addedUser = response.body()
                    Log.d("responsee",""+addedUser)
                    onResult(addedUser.data)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

now in getQuotes you will have that `it` is a UserInfo object

```
    apiService.addUser(userInfo) {
        val returnedUserInfo = it
    }
```

Comment: ok thanks, one more thing how to call data class here as an parameter val userInfo = UserInfo()?

Comment: where you do `val addedUser = response.body()` the `addedUser` will be the `UserInfo` object.

Comment: Please check the getQuotes function, i want to call UserInfo Class there

Comment: ah yeah I misunderstood. I will update the answer in a moment

Comment: @Khurria_55 check the edit

Comment: Thankyou so much :) I Understood

Answer (score 0):

just follow my steps :

```
File->settings->Plugins
```

search for `JSON To Kotlin class` and install it

again click on `File->New->Kotlin Data class from JSON`

paste your json code here and click on generate. It will generate POJO classes and you will good to go.

Comment: Please read my question again. I have already done with these classes

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed, is that the data in your json is:

```
"Quote": "The pain you feel today will be the strength you feel tomorrow.",
"Author": ""
```

While your `UserInfo` defined  `@SerializedName("message")` for `Quote`.

Comment: Yes, i have updated it, but still i am getting null on Quote and Author in response.